# Calculating the mean value of a column with complex number based on the datetime column in r

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime

I have a data frame and want to calculate the mean of values in one column including complex numbers based on the time. my data frame is something like the following:

'''
datetime <- c(2022-10-01 01:00:00, 2022-10-01 01:00:00,2022-10-01 01:00:00,2022-10-01 01:00:00,
2022-10-01 01:30:00, 2022-10-01 01:30:00,2022-10-01 01:30:00,2022-10-01 01:30:00 )
A <- c(2+3i, 2+4i, 2.5+3i, 2+3i, 5+2i, 5+2i, 5.2+3i, 5+3.1i)
df <- data.frame(A)
'''
I want to calculate the mean of column A at 1different time and end up with this:
'''
datetime <- c(2022-10-01 01:00:00, 2022-10-01 01:00:00,2022-10-01 01:00:00,2022-10-01 01:00:00,
2022-10-01 01:30:00, 2022-10-01 01:30:00,2022-10-01 01:30:00,2022-10-01 01:30:00 )
A <- c(2+3i, 2+4i, 2.5+3i, 2+3i, 5+2i, 5+2i, 5.2+3i, 5+3.1i)
df <- data.frame(A)
'''
I used this code:
'''
agg_df = aggregate(df[ , A], by=list(df2$datetime), FUN=mean)
'''
But there is an error:
"
! Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
x Subscript `P2_cal` has the wrong type `complex`.
i It must be logical, numeric, or character.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
"

Comment: Is it from the same data?  This works `aggregate(A ~ datetime, df, mean)` for me

Comment: it worked, thank you. How can I save and plot now the new data frame after aggregation?

Comment: Just assign to a new object as in the solution below

Comment: Then for plotting use `plot(out$A)`

Answer (score 0):

We could use the formula method

```
out <- aggregate(A ~ datetime, df, mean)
out
    datetime            A
1 2022-10-01 01:00:00 2.125+3.250i
2 2022-10-01 01:30:00 5.050+2.525i
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(date = c("1997-12-15", "1998-01-15", "1998-02-15", 
"1998-03-15", "1998-04-15", "1998-05-15", "1998-06-15", "1998-07-15", 
"1998-08-15", "1998-09-15", "1998-10-15", "1998-11-15", "1998-12-15", 
"1999-01-15", "1999-02-15", "1999-03-15", "1999-04-15", "1999-05-15", 
"1999-06-15", "1999-07-15", "1999-08-15", "1999-09-15", "1999-10-15", 
"1999-11-15", "1999-12-15"), overall = c(17.548, 16.189, 15.667, 
15.509, 16.709, 18.822, 22.722, 25.372, 26.597, 25.256, 22.857, 
20.242, 17.179, 16.003, 15.14, 15.522, 16.537, 19.658, 23.245, 
25.313, 26.753, 26.04, 23.843, 20.94, 17.842), eastern = c(18.751, 
17.155, 16.504, 16.208, 17.702, 19.66, 23.512, 25.912, 27.226, 
26.151, 24.44, 21.867, 18.797, 17.206, 16.345, 16.689, 17.521, 
20.74, 24.161, 26.053, 27.112, 26.597, 24.94, 22.375, 19.439)),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25"))
```